# Validations outside the scope of a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I have a report model which has many tools. Each tool has a working_hours attribute. The working hours attribute represents the total hours the tool has been used - you know, to keep track of servicing times.

The idea of the validation in question is to make sure that the tool is not used for more than 24 hours in a day. I have tried the following code

```
class DayHoursValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each record, key, value
    most_recent_report = Report.where('tool_name LIKE ?', "%#{record.report.tool_name}%").last
    record.errors[key] << "has done more than 24 hours in a day" if value - most_recent_report.toolbox[attrubute] > 24
  end
end
```

I get an error in the `#{record.report.tool_name}` aspect of the code because the `report_id` for the record is nil.

In the controller, I have `@report.build_toolbox` which - I think - should build the association; thereby setting the `report_id`

How do I go about fixing this? Thanks